# What is the length $RQ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

> $O1S = 4 cm, O2Q = \sqrt 3 cm, TP = 4 cm, QR = ...$

$QR = 3cm$ based on equilateral triangle is that true?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption  "If we continue $O_1P$, it passes from $O_2$" is necessary. Assume C is a point in QR such that $QC=CR$ . we conclude $O_1PC$ is a line. the  Two triangles PCR and $PSO_1$ are similar. So $\frac{RC}{4}=\frac{PR}{PT+PO_1}=\frac{PR}{8} $  So $\frac{RC}{PR}=\frac{1}{2}$ and the triangle PQR is equilateral.‌ Therefore $O_2QC=30 \ \text{degree}$ and $O_2C=\frac{1}{2}QO_2=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. So $QR=2 QC=2\sqrt{(QO_2)^2-(O_2C)^2}=2\sqrt{3-\frac{3}{4}}=3$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> $|O_1S|=4$, $|O_2Q|=\sqrt3$, $|TP|=4$, $|QR|=\dots$

\begin{align}
\sin O_1PS&=\frac{|O_1S|}{|O_1P|}=\frac{|O_1S|}{|O_1S|+|TP|}=\frac12
\end{align}

hence, $\triangle PSU$ is equilateral,
as well as $\triangle PRQ$.

Hence, $O_2Q$ is the circumradius of 
equilateral $\triangle PRQ$ and
\begin{align} 
|QR|&=\frac32\cdot|O_2Q|\cdot \frac 2{\sqrt3}
=3
.
\end{align}

Comment: Why using law of cosines $QO^2 + OR^2 - 2QOOR\cos 60 = QR^2$ i get $QR = \sqrt 3$?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: $\angle QO_2R=$?..